# Entities Not Being Reused

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I've got a new ASP.NET MVC 4 application that I'm starting to play around with. I've used Entity-Framework in the past, but this is my first experience with Code First. The trouble I'm having is that when a new `PLAYER` is added, a new record in the `POSITIONS` is also added, even though there's already a record in that table that matches.

### Controller

```
Player player = new Player();
player.PlayerName = "Bob";

PositionRepository posRepo = new PositionRepository();
player.PlayerPosition = posRepo.Get(1);

PlayerRepository playerRepo = new PlayerRepository();

playerRepo.Add(player);
```

### Player Repo

```
public Player Add(Player player)
    {
        _db.Players.Add(player);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return player;
    }
```

### Position Repo

```
public Position Get(int id)
    {
        return _db.Positions.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id == id);
    }
```

I can include code for the Player and Position classes as well if that would help.

To sum: When I add the new `PLAYER` record, I want it to reference an existing `POSITION` record. In the case above, I just grab the first `POSITION` record. Instead, a new `POSITION` record is created for the player.

Interestingly enough, if I construct multiple players in a loop, only one new `POSITION` record is created. It's still a problem, because I don't want any new `POSITION` records created, but to use the one already in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quick guess.

the Position record is recreated because you use different instance of DbContext on `PlayerRepository` and `PositionRepository` so the Position record lost its current state.

it is a common problem when using repository pattern and ORM. not yet try it but i think it will work

```
public Player Add(Player player)
{
    //add this
    _db.Entry(player.PlayerPosition).State = EntityState.Modified;

    _db.Players.Add(player);
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return player;
}
```

Comment: You were absolutely correct. I was creating too many DbContext instances. Thanks for the help!